# Fading div in and out on center slider item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fade a div in/out on a center slider item.
I'm using `owl-slider`, the center slide/item gets assigned the class `.center` by the slider.

Each slide has a div called Age, and I'm trying to make it so this Age div is hidden on all slides which don't have the `.center` class, and it fades in on the center slide.

The center slide is navigated by the `owl-prev`/`owl-next` controls, so this is what I was thinking to trigger the change.

Is it a more efficient way to do this?

Example:

The issue I'm having is how to test for the presence of the .center class on document load, and also how to initially set the Age div not visible on load also.

I've tried `$(".item-age").hide();` and it works, but when I click the next control all Age divs appear, not just the one associated with .center.

This is what I'm trying: `

```
    $(".owl-next").click(function(){
        if ($('.owl-item').hasClass('center')){
                $('.item-age').fadeIn();

            }
    });`
```

Comment: People here will take 'hours' or even may not answer unless you post some code.!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to use CSS with [Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Define the two states for the age div:

```
.age {
    opacity: 0; /* transparent = invisible */
}
.center .age {
    opacity: 1; /* opaque = visible */
}
```

This already does the trick for hiding/showing the age div. To get the fading effekt, add css transition properties:

```
.age {
    opacity: 0; /* transparent = invisible */
    transition: opacity 1s; /* fade out transition */
}
.center .age {
    opacity: 1; /* opaque = visible */
    transition: opacity 500ms; /* fade in transition */
}
```

The transition is always defined in the *target* state of the transition. To get a better understanding of the transition-property refer to [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    if ($('.sliderItem').hasClass('center')){
        $('.age').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.fadeIn()` function on the element that has the `.center` class directly by changing your selector target to `.owl-item.center`.

Try changing your code to:

```
$(".owl-next").click(function () {
    $('.owl-item.center .item-age').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to fade in the 'item-age' div which is a child of the owl-item.center div, not the whole owl-item.center div itself, any ideas?

Comment: Please see the update, forgot to add the next selector. It should fadeIn .item-age now.